# MySQL.. What should be the query

Tags: mysql

I need your help.

I have a table named Users and in the columns id, name, age, ageMax.

What should be the query which increase each user age of 1 if his age is less than ageMax?

Comment: Have you created a query yet? What does it do right and wrong?

Comment: UPDATE Users set age = age+1 WHERE age < ageMax

Comment: How  you get the ageMax ?.. is calculated by an aggregation function as MAX? or is a knowed  value ?..  please update you question and add the data schema  and a proper data sample

Comment: ageMax is knowed value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
Update Users
Set age = age + 1
Where age<ageMax
```